# How to use match case to check for variable type in python?

Tags: types, pattern-matching, python-3.10

I have this code to check for whether or not a variable is a number or a `Vector2` in my `Vector2` class when multiplying.

```py
def __mul__(self, other):
    match type(other):
        case int | float:
            pass
        case Vector2:
            pass
```

If I run this, I get `SyntaxError: name capture 'int' makes remaining patterns unreachable`, and when I hover in vscode, it gives me:

```
"int" is not accessed
Irrefutable pattern allowed only as the last subpattern in an "or" pattern
All subpatterns within an "or" pattern must target the same names
Missing names: "float"
Irrefutable pattern is allowed only for the last case statement
```

If I remove  `| float` it still won't work, so I can't make them separate cases.

Comment: you can take hints from this explanation:
https://stackabuse.com/python-check-if-variable-is-a-number/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Case with a variable (ex: `case _:` or `case other:`) needs to be the last `case` in the list. It matches any value, where the value was not matched by a previous case, and captures that value in the variable.

A type can be used in a case, but implies `isinstance()`, testing to determine if the value being matched is an instance of that type. Therefore, the value used for the match should be the actual variable `other` rather than the type `type(other)`, since `type(other)` is a type whose type would match `type()`.

```py
def __mul__(self, other):
    match other:
        case int() | float():
            pass
        case Vector2():
            pass
```

Comment: This pattern is called a class pattern: "A class pattern provides support for destructuring arbitrary objects". More information can be found in the documentation: https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#class-patterns

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why no one has given this as an example:

```py
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

class C:
    pass


def check_type(obj: Union[A, B, C]):
    match obj:
        case x if isinstance(x, A):
            return "A"
        case x if isinstance(x, B):
            return "B"
        case x if isinstance(x, C):
            return "C"
        case _:
            return "Unknown"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    b = B()
    c = C()
    print(check_type(a))
    print(check_type(b))
    print(check_type(c))
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
```

Correct me if I am wrong but to me this seems exactly what the OP is requesting.

Comment: I agree - this is definitely the right way to go if you want full type coverage - checking functions using the `Callable` type, for example

Answer (score -1):

Since this is the first result for "How to use match case to check for variable type in python?" this might answer your question as well as many others (Python 3.10+):

```py
def print_type(v):
    match v:
        # None must come before int
        case None:
            print("NONE")
        # bool() must come before int
        case bool():
            print("BOOL")
        case int():
            print("INT")
        case float():
            print("FLOAT")
        case Vector2():
            print("VECTOR2")
        case str():
            print("STR")
```

Examples:

```py
print_type(1)  # prints INT
a = 1
print_type(a)  # prints INT
print_type(None)  # prints NONE
print_type("Hello")  # prints STR
v = Vector2()
print_type(v)  # prints VECTOR2
```

Read more about this in the [documentation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#class-patterns) (thanks: @charelf)